# why we use word "just" in "Maybe a"

Tags: haskell

why in definition of Maybe is :

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

Why definition isn't like this:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | a
```

Why we use Just, isn't be simple wihout this ?

Comment: This is a duplicate, I'll see if I can find it. Long story short, you need a constructor to differentiate types. `a` would just be an unwrapped type, not a type wrapped in `Maybe`.

Comment: This is the difference between [tagged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) and untagged unions. Haskell uses the latter.

Comment: The former, not the latter.